# When Silent Image Is Disbelieved, Is It Transparent?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

I love illusions, including *Silent Image*, but unfortunately I don't think it's always handled correctly. I'd like to clarify the RAW interpretation of this spell for this purpose.

Here is the text of the spell:

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible
>   phenomenon that is no larger than a 15-foot cube. 
>   [...]
>
> Physical interaction with the image reveals it to be an illusion,
>   because things can pass through it. [...] If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the creature
>   can see through the image.

When *Silent Image* is cast, and this image has been revealed to be illusory, do they still *see* the image as opaque? Unlike spells like *Minor Illusion*, this spell does not specify that creatures can see this illusion as if it was transparent.

It does say: *If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the creature can see through the image.* I don't think this is supposed to be taken literally, otherwise it would have said *the illusion becomes faint to the creature* as it does for *Minor Illusion*. Also, "to see through something" is an idiomatic expression meaning "to understand the true nature of something."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Translucent, but yes.**

I’d read the verbiage to imply that they can discern it is an illusion and see the reality through it.  So despite not having the exact same wording, I’d argue the RAI is that it matches Minor Illusion, as similar wording of “see through” is used in Blur (which does add “as with True Sight”). And in all the cases the wording is not "see through the illusion" which would be the common idiom. Instead it says that they "see through the image".

Moreover, if it was the idiomatic use of the phrase, it would be useless tautology. It would read, nonsensically, "If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the creature can tell it is an illusion." Which would be throw away sentence.

Hallucinatory Terrian is a 4th level spell, and silent image is a 1st. It would seem unbalanced for the 1st level to provide disadvantage even when someone knows it is an illusion and the 4th level not to.